# web.config file references cannot be found in intellisense

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, user-controls, tagprefix

I have referenced multiple user controls within the web.config file, because I was receiving an error in the individual pages and they are used in multiple pages, the code I wrote is as follows:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="confirm_list" src="~/Controls/confirmed_participant_list.ascx"/>
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="contact_us" src="~/Controls/contact_us.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="erh_list" src="~/Controls/erh_list.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="graphic_with_thumbnail" src="~/Controls/graphic_with_thumbnail.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="header" src="~/Controls/header.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="footer" src="~/Controls/footer.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="main_tnavbar" src="~/Controls/main_tnavbar.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="program_header" src="~/Controls/program_header.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="program_list" src="~/Controls/program_list.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="signup_section" src="~/Controls/signup_section.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="speaker_list" src="~/Controls/speaker_list.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="IPAMControl" tagName="track" src="~/Controls/track.ascx" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

However, when I go into the HTML markup file (aspx) and beging typing "`<IPAM...`" nothing appears and I get an error of "Unrecognized namespace 'IPAMControls'.

Below is a sample page I am trying to insert one of the controls into:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterNew.master" CodeFile="~/programs/programs.aspx.cs" Inherits="IPAM.Website.programs.programs" %>
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    <h1>Upcoming Programs</h1>
<hr size="1">
<p align="center"><a href="#long" class="bodylink">Long Programs</a> | <a href="#workshops" class="bodylink">Workshops</a> | <a href="#affiliate" class="bodylink">Affiliates' & Other Workshops</a> | <a href="#summer" class="bodylink">Summer Programs &amp; Special Events</a>
</p>


Our upcoming programs include long programs, short programs (workshops), reunion conferences, and summer programs. Click on the program title for detailed information.
    <%--<a name="long"><ipam:program_list id="idProgramList1" Type="Long" Time="Upcoming" runat="server" /></a>
    <a name="workshops"><ipam:program_list id="idProgramList2" Type="Short" Time="Upcoming" runat="server" /></a> 
    <a name="affiliate"><ipam:program_list id="idProgramList3" Type="Affiliate" Time="Upcoming" runat="server" /></a>
    <a name="summer"><ipam:program_list id="idProgramList5" Type="Summer" Time="Upcoming" runat="server" /></a>
    <a name="special"><ipam:program_list ID="idProgramList6" Type="Special" Time="Upcoming" runat="server" /></a>--%>
</asp:Content>
```

What am I doing wrong or missing.

Comment: I need someone who is willing to actually look at the question and help figure out why this isnt working, instead of just telling me how to use a user control

Answer (score 1):

You use user controls like this:

```
<IPAMControl:confirm_list ID="<id>" runat="server"></IPAMControl:confirm_list>
```

I use VS2008 and it doesn't come up in my intellisense either.

[Edit]

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="accesscontrol_test" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="IPAMControl" TagName="confirm_list" Src="Copy of nav.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="NEContent" Runat="Server">
<h1>Upcoming Programs</h1>
<hr size="1">
<p align="center"><a href="#long" >Long Programs</a></p>


Our upcoming programs include long programs, short programs (workshops), reunion 
conferences, and summer programs. Click on the program title for detailed information.
<a name="long"><IPAMControl:confirm_list id="idconfirm_list" runat="server">
</IPAMControl:confirm_list></a>
</asp:Content>
```

The above code works fine for me, try registering it at the top of the page like I did, then we can help pinpoint what's causing the issue. You'll obviously have to change the directives, but register it in the page and not the web config.

[Edit]

Try adding this to your web config in `<pages><controls>`

```
<add tagPrefix="IMAPControl" namespace="IMAP.Webmaster.Controls" assembly="IMAP.Webmaster" />
```

Comment: I know how to use them, but my question is, why am I receiving an error that IPAMControls is an Unrecognized namespace and intellisense is not working with these (Im using VS2008)

Comment: Oh, the pages that I am trying to add them in are child pages to MasterPageFiles, could that be the problem and if so how do I correct it

Comment: When you were registering the user control on a page, were you still getting the same error or different?

Comment: I was getting another error all together (" Element is not known element") <-- That is the error message I am receiving. I apologize for being so testy too, this is something that I have not been able to get any help on whatsoever.

Comment: I added a sample of a page the controls are being placed into

Comment: Ok, this might get rid of the Element is not known, in your bin folder, delete Register.dll and App_Licenses.dll if they exists then rebuild your website.

Comment: Those two files are not created when you build a web application, so I do not have those, nor have I ever seen them

Comment: Check my edits, because if that doesn't work for you, I'll have to check something else..

Comment: The only issue I have with registering it in each page is that there are over 100 pages I have to do this for.

Comment: Oh and another thing I noticed (might not matter but worth the quick thought). The main namespace fo the web app is IPAM.Webmaster, and I am simply extending the namespace to be like IPAM.Webmaster.Helpers, IPAM.Webmaster.Controls for different functionalities of the app. Could this have been the kiss of death

Comment: Well sometimes you'll get the Element is not known.. because there was an error in your codebehind files.. you might want to try making sure you have spelled things properly.

Comment: LOL yeah I just painstackingly went through for the past two days making sure everything was spelled correctly.

Comment: Hey, read up more on this, describes a user control within another control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680519/in-web-config-is-it-possible-to-register-all-user-controls-in-specified-directory

Comment: Im getting some real wierd stuff now, I am getting "Could not load type 'IPAM.Website.programs.programs" and I am also getting "The type or namspace name 'App_Classes' does not exist in the namespace 'IPAM'" (this error is referring to namespace IPAM.App_Classes, in the App_Classes folder.

Comment: Actually theseuser controls are not being used in other control, they are being used in simple aspx pages. I did try what you suggested and this is what I got:    "Could not load type 'IPAM.Controls.confirmed_participant_list'."