# Register user control in web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, namespaces

Implementing user controls inside the same project, I am trying to reference them in web.config in order to not include the Register clause in every page.

Registering one single control it is working:

```
<pages>
    <controls>
       <add tagPrefix="myApp" src="/Controls/WebUserControl1.ascx" tagName="WebUserControl1"/>
    </controls>
</pages>
```

But if I try to register all the controls in the namespace, it is not working:

```
<add tagPrefix="myApp" namespace="myApp.Web"/>
```

responding with the error:

Unknown server tag 'myApp:WebUserControl1'.

I am using VB.NET and I suspect that could be something related with Namespaces. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Web.config Is it possible to register all user controls in specified directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680519/in-web-config-is-it-possible-to-register-all-user-controls-in-specified-director)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<add tagPrefix="myApp" namespace="myApp.Web.UI.Controls"/>
```

Comment: Didn't work. The control is in myApp.Web Namespace, so it should be:
<add tagPrefix="myApp" namespace="myApp.Web"/> (I edited the question)