# Why I can't access to my own User Control?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, user-controls

Following this [guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc185061.aspx), I've created my own User Control and registered into the webconfig:

```
public partial class usercontrols_LinkBoxAttivita : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

On Home.ascx I've included this:

```
<myOwnControls:LinkBoxAttivita ID="LinkBoxAttivita1" runat="server" />
```

It works, and it is rendered. Now, why on the codebehind of Home.ascx.cs I can't access to it?

LinkBoxAttivita1 seems unexistent. I want to set from here the MyProp value to it.

This is how I registered it:

```
<system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="myOwnControls" tagName="LinkBoxAttivita" src="~/usercontrols/LinkBoxAttivita.ascx" />
        </controls>
    </pages> 
</system.web>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you dragged the `UserControl` to the designer? Otherwise the designer won't create the `@Register` directive, which is required for the page to recognize the user control.

[How to: Include a User Control in an ASP.NET Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Example (from MSDN):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Spinner" 
    Src="~/Controls/Spinner.ascx" %>
<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <uc:Spinner id="Spinner1" 
        runat="server" 
        MinValue="1" 
        MaxValue="10" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: As I said I regitered it inside web.config. So I don't need anymore to register it to the page, every time: `<system.web><pages><controls><add tagPrefix="myOwnControls" tagName="LinkBoxAttivita" src="~/usercontrols/LinkBoxAttivita.ascx" /></controls></pages></system.web>`

Comment: @markzzz: whoops, sorry, overlooked it. You have mentioned that you've followed a guideline (which is in italian btw), can you show how you have registered it? Because there must be a difference, otherwise it would work. Also, are the `User Controls` nested? I'm asking because here is a question where the accepted answer mentions a problem with nested controls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680519/in-web-config-is-it-possible-to-register-all-user-controls-in-specified-director

Comment: What do you mean with "nested". I added how I configured it inside web.config. I include it inside another UserControl Home.ascx (which is in another folder).

Comment: Now I see what he means with nested. But shouldn't be a problem, since the 3° point. Home.ascx (which is in /context) and the user control (which is in /usercontrol) are already in different places.

Comment: Oh wait, now it works? Seems that Visual Studio has wake up from a nightmare? :O